# How to save fields from APIs into objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've built APIs for stores weekly reports.
Then I've realized that I have an issue that is the reports are showing on my front-end but are not being stored in the database.

Do I have to redevelop all the APIs after implementing models for reports? or is there another way to go around it?

Comment: This is far too broad and impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you are definitely going to have to alter the APIs in order to have them save when they are accessed. It may be worth while as well to consider building some kind of caching system so if you end up having to do some deeply database intensive calls (multi joins or deeply complicated aggregates in general), you can simply read from a file that has completed that task once before (Assuming the report has some static components).

Depending on the size of the objects returned. You should be able to easily store them in JSON format (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). You can put that directly into the database as a "text" field in SQL or pass dictionaries natively if you are using Mongo. Then when you want them, call to that spot in the DB and then easily convert the object returned back into a dictionary for you to parse on the front end easily. I've often used this approach, just because getting stuff into Associative arrays is almost always the end result before rendering the dom anyway.

I hope this helps some or at least gives you a few ideas to make this a bit easier!

Comment: Thank you so much. Isn’t there a way to write models that saves the values coming from APIs from same project? This way APIs will still be working fine and the data are stored.